# Running a SQLite query from the bottom to the top of the table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to increment the primary integer key field (_id) of an Android SQLite database table by 1 for all records with initial _id values greater than 21.

I have tried the following:

`UPDATE tableName SET _id = _id+1 WHERE _id > 21`

But upon completing the first update to the table (changing 22 to 23), there are 2 records with _id = 23. This creates an error. Is there a way to avoid the problem by running this process from the last record to the first as opposed to starting from the top?

The reverse process:`UPDATE tableName SET _id = _id-1 WHERE _id > 21` works without errors when _id = 21 is not present so the problem with the first statement is definitely relating to the doubling up of ids.

I am trying to use DESC ordering to solve this problem. My current code is the following but it's not the right syntax and this only increments the last record:

`UPDATE tableName SET _id = _id+1 WHERE _id = (SELECT _id FROM tableName WHERE _id > 21 ORDER BY _id DESC)`

Comment: Why would you need to update an id?

Comment: First fetch records DESC and update them on a loop.

Comment: @laalto - there is a gap in the database due to a record being deleted and I need the database ids to be consecutive numbers for several other pieces of code to function correctly.

Comment: @MousaJafari - That's the solution I have been working on but I can't seem to find the correct syntax. Please see the edit in the question

Comment: Consider fixing your other code. Identifier should not change once assigned.

Comment: Agreed. In any database with transactions, you cannot guarantee that your DB IDs will be sequential. Writing code that relies on sequential IDs is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can first fetch records descending and then update them

```
    // query
    String sql = "SELECT _id FROM tableName WHERE _id > 21 ORDER BY _id DESC";

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db
            .rawQuery(sql, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        do {

            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

            // update related record

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Comment: I was looking for a SQLite way to do this rather than a Java way but I guess this is good enough as I only need to do this once for each user.